# Understanding poor quality answers

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, first-post-review

In First Posts Review, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/12076488) is flagged as poor quality and I'd like to understand why so I'm able to apply the principle to other reviews.  It's my understanding that a poor quality answer is worthless and we'd all be better off if it was deleted.

The review question pertains to a boot problem related to the OS and Visual Studio.  The answer states that removing the graphics driver solved the problem.  In my experience, this response is a possible solution.  The OP states the problem occurred after an OS update and the computer will boot to safe mode.  Both the OS update and booting to safe mode could indicate a driver problem.

Why is the suggestion that this could be a graphics driver problem a worthless response?

[image: firstpost]

Comment: "Reinstall XXXXX" is unlikely good answer to *good SO question* - better action would be to re-read question itself and act on question instead. It is perfectly fine to open question in separate tab if you are not sure if post is on-topic as some other answers may turn out to be good SO posts.

Comment: I need to complain after the fact: its a bit of a jump in severity from "low quality" to "worthless". Its not a queue to review worthless answers.

Comment: @Gimby - if it's deemed poor quality, it gets deleted, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First Post audits are a bit unusual in that they draw in posts that wouldn't be used for audits in other queues.

Specifically, they draw in posts that are just plain *mediocre*. They may technically be answers, and indeed may even be *correct* answers, but they're poorly-written, redundant, confusing, badly-formatted, etc.

Why? Because **these sorts of posts require some action**. Let's examine the instructions for First Post review:

[image: This is the first answer posted by a new user. Help them learn to use the site by reviewing their post.]

Note the purpose of the review: *to help a new user learn to use the site.* There are plenty of ways in which you could do this: edits, votes, comments, flags... Whatever is necessary to guide the budding author in a direction that'll help them be productive in the future.

You didn't do any of that though. You clicked "No Action Needed". If that'd been a real answer (and it was, once upon a time), your review would've accomplished nothing. And no one else would've been assigned the review. The author would've gone on unaware that his answer was poorly-written, unhelpful, unclear.

A bit of advice for future reviews in this queue: "No Action Needed" isn't a synonym for "Skip"; **it's a declaration that you fully understand the situation and see no opportunity for action.** Use it only when you've read the post, understood it, evaluated it, and can find *no* opportunity to make a useful contribution to it.

In this case, a downvote, a comment, perhaps even an edit would've been a useful and welcome action, something that could've helped the neophyte contributor to gain the confidence and understanding needed to participate here. If you didn't see this, then you didn't take the time to understand the answer and the problem it purported to solve. Next time, please take the time to do so... Or just skip.

Answer (score -2):

The question says: My computer will not boot.

The answer says: I got VS to work.

---

It's a really subtle difference, I can understand your confusion.

Comment: This goes against the guidance given by moderators / SE employees that "an answer to a different question" does NOT count as "not an answer" and may not be deleted by ordinary users through the review queues. This should not be an audit.

Comment: @AndrewMedico It fails to answer the question, and thus is a poor answer. The purpose of first posts is to help newcomers become contributing members. Many posts which cannot be flagged as "NAA" are crap that we should stop newcomers from producing as much as possible.

Comment: @AndrewMedico So you think that an answer being completely wrong and unrelated to the question being asked doesn't merit a downvote, a comment, perhaps an edit, or *any* other action?